# Genus of curves embedded into some projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, plane-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

The Plucker formula allows one to calculate the genus of a curve embedded into $\mathbf{P}^2$.

Does there exist a "higher-dimensional" analogue of the Plucker formula? More precisely, let $f_1,\ldots,f_{n-1}$ be homogenous polynomials in $k[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and let $C$ be the curve defined by $f_1=0,\ldots,f_{n-1}=0$ in $\mathbf{P}^n$. Is there a formula to compute the genus of $C$ in terms of easy data depending only on $f_1,\ldots,f_{n-1}$?

Comment: Would you consider the Hilbert polynomial as "easy data"?

Comment: There is Exercise II 8.4 (g) in Hartshorne which says that, for $n=3$, if $C$ is nonsingular $f_1$ and $f_2$ define nonsingular hypersurfaces of degrees $d_1$ and $d_2$, you have 
$p_g=\tfrac 12 d_1 d_2(d_1+d_2-4) + 1$. This might all be generalized, but what are you willing to assume? You are clearly willing to assume that $C$ is a complete intersection, but what about singularities?

Comment: @curious. I think I consider the Hilbert polynomial as "easy data".
To rattle. I want to take care of singularities too. Let's keep them ordinary double if that helps. This way $C$ is a stable curve. The usual Plucker formula gives a formula in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879808826291) does it for you (also available [here](http://www.bilkent.edu.tr/~sertoz/papers/genus.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the Hilbert polynomial $P_C$ *"easy data"*, then you can use the formula 
$$p_a(C) = (-1)^{\dim(C)} (P_C(0)-1)$$
to calculate the *arithmetic* genus. See, e.g. Hartshorne Exercise I.7.2.